# What's the "right notion of sameness" for models?

Tags: model-theory

What constitute "different models" from the perspective of model theory?

The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ are a model of Peano arithmetic, here denoted $T_{PA}$.

I'm going to define $\mathbb{N}$ for the purposes of this question as the familiar construction $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}, \cdots$ where $\in$ is $\le_{\mathbb{N}}$.

It seems pretty clear that $\mathbb{N} \models T_{PA}$, in fact, scraping away some of the detail of $\mathbb{N}$ is the point.

I can define a different model, $\mathbb{P} \subsetneq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, where each element of $\mathbb{P}$ is an ordered pair of the same number (in the set construction above).

$$ \mathbb{P} := \{ (\emptyset, \emptyset)\; , \;\; (\{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset\})\; , \;\; (\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}) \; , \;\; \cdots \} $$

With $\le_\mathbb{P}, +_\mathbb{P}, *_\mathbb{P}$ defined pointwise using  $\le_\mathbb{N}, +_\mathbb{N}, \text{and} \;\; *_\mathbb{N}$, respectively

$(\mathbb{N}, \le_\mathbb{N}, +_\mathbb{N}, *_\mathbb{N})$ and $(\mathbb{P}, \le_\mathbb{P}, +_\mathbb{P}, *_\mathbb{P})$ are not literally the same, but they also aren't different in an interesting way.

To use an analogy from programming, it seems like models are *particular programs written in some language $L$* and a theory $T$ is like an API, giving you signatures for functions and predicates as well as contracts that the implementation is required to obey. In the case above, $L$ seems to be a not-entirely-nailed-down set theory ... whose existence we are using to "breathe life into" our model and give it an existence independent of our theory.

Taking a step back from $L$ as set theory and just thinking of it like a generic programming language ... there's no obvious notion of sameness to me that's coarser than "textually equal"/"literally the same" and finer than "every model that models the same theory is equal".

What is the correct way of thinking about model sameness/equality?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of **isomorphism** in model theory?

Comment: @NoahSchweber that's the concept I'm having trouble understanding. I'm trying to figure out much of a "white box" models need to be for a useful notion of isomorphism to even be possible. I know the question's elementary ...

Comment: There is more than one useful notion of model equivalence.  Model isomorphism is perhaps the strongest equivalence (finest granularity), and "elementary equivalence" is a weaker condition that asks merely that any closed sentence true in one model is also true in the other model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, two structures *(in the sense of first-order logic - that is, a set together with some labelled relations, functions, and constants)* are considered "the same" if and only if they are **isomorphic**:

> If $\Sigma$ is a first-order language, then two $\Sigma$-structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are isomorphic if there is a bijection $i$ between their domains which "preserves the $\Sigma$-structure" - e.g. for each unary function symbol $f$ in $\Sigma$ we need to have $i(f^\mathcal{A}(x))=f^\mathcal{B}(i(x))$ for every $x$ in the domain of $\mathcal{A}$.

This notion is - as you expected - much finer than elementary equivalence (= "have the same theory"), and much coarser than "textual equality" as you call it (in particular, it identifies the two versions of the naturals you describe).

Comment: Didn't you forget what $i$ has to satisfy wrt the relation symbols ?

Comment: @Max And non-unary function symbols, and constant symbols - hence my "e.g."

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen the e.g., sorry !